# Integrating Wicket and Enunciate

Tags: java, web-services, maven, wicket, enunciate

I am now learning how to integrate wicket and enunciate by following this article http://docs.codehaus.org/display/ENUNCIATE/A+Rich+Web+service+API+for+Wicket. But the results is different from that site. The api folder was succesfully generated but when I pointed to the API in xml or json or rest or soap, I can't access them.

Here are info I got when I tried to "mvn:jetty-run" in cmd :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Wicket Examples 1.5.7
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> jetty-maven-plugin:7.4.2.v20110526:run (default-cli) @ wicket-example
s >>>
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex/maven-metadata.xm
l from/to java.net.1 (http://download.java.net/maven/1): No connector available
to access repository java.net.1 (http://download.java.net/maven/1) of type legac
y using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enunciate-spring-plugin:1.18:assemble (default) @ wicket-exampl
es ---
[INFO] C:\Users\AGI\Downloads\apache-wicket-1.5.7\src\wicket-examples\enunciate.
xml exists, so it will be used.
[INFO] initializing enunciate.
[INFO] invoking enunciate:generate step...
[INFO] [c] Skipping C code generation because everything appears up-to-date.
[INFO] [csharp] Skipping C# code generation because everything appears up-to-dat
e.
[INFO] [jaxws-ri] Skipping generation of JAX-WS RI support as everything appears
 up-to-date....
[INFO] [jaxws-support] Skipping JAX-WS support generation as everything appears
up-to-date...
[INFO] [jersey] Skipping generation of JAX-RS support files because everything a
ppears up-to-date.
[INFO] [obj-c] Skipping C code generation because everything appears up-to-date.

[INFO] [ruby] Skipping Ruby code generation because everything appears up-to-dat
e.
[INFO] [xml] Skipping generation of XML files since everything appears up-to-dat
e...
[INFO] [jaxws-client] Skipping generation of JAX-WS Client sources as everything
 appears up-to-date...
[INFO] [docs] Skipping documentation source generation as everything appears up-
to-date...
[INFO] [spring-app] Skipping generation of spring config files as everything app
ears up-to-date...
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[INFO] invoking enunciate:compile step...
[INFO] [jaxws-client] Skipping compilation of JAX-WS client classes as everythin
g appears up-to-date...
[INFO] invoking enunciate:build step...
[INFO] [jaxws-client] Skipping creation of JAX-WS client jar as everything appea
rs up-to-date...
[INFO] [jaxws-client] Skipping creation of the JAX-WS client source jar as every
thing appears up-to-date...
[INFO] [basic-app] Skipping the build of the expanded war as everything appears
up-to-date...
[INFO] invoking enunciate:package step...
[INFO] closing enunciate.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.2:process (default) @ wicket-examples
 ---
[INFO] Setting property: classpath.resource.loader.class => 'org.codehaus.plexus
.velocity.ContextClassLoaderResourceLoader'.
[INFO] Setting property: velocimacro.messages.on => 'false'.
[INFO] Setting property: resource.loader => 'classpath'.
[INFO] Setting property: resource.manager.logwhenfound => 'false'.
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex/maven-metadata.xml from h
ttp://download.java.net/maven/1 was cached in the local repository, resolution w
ill not be reattempted until the update interval of java.net.1 has elapsed or up
dates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer metadata org.jvnet.staxex:s
tax-ex/maven-metadata.xml from/to java.net.1 (http://download.java.net/maven/1):
 No connector available to access repository java.net.1 (http://download.java.ne
t/maven/1) of type legacy using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnector
Factory
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ wicket-e
xamples ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 661 resources
[INFO] Copying 12 resources
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.4:compile (default-compile) @ wicket-examples
 ---
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to C:\Users\AGI\Downloads\apache-wicket-1.5.7\sr
c\wicket-examples\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.2.0:manifest (bundle-manifest) @ wicket-example
s ---
[WARNING] Ignoring project type war - supportedProjectTypes = [jar, bundle]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @
wicket-examples ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.4:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ wicket-
examples ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< jetty-maven-plugin:7.4.2.v20110526:run (default-cli) @ wicket-example
s <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jetty-maven-plugin:7.4.2.v20110526:run (default-cli) @ wicket-example
s ---
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: Wicket Examples
[INFO] Webapp source directory = C:\Users\AGI\Downloads\apache-wicket-1.5.7\src\
wicket-examples\src\main\webapp
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: automatic
[INFO] Classes = C:\Users\AGI\Downloads\apache-wicket-1.5.7\src\wicket-examples\
target\classes
[INFO] Context path = /
[INFO] Tmp directory = C:\Users\AGI\Downloads\apache-wicket-1.5.7\src\wicket-exa
mples\target\tmp
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file = file:/C:/Users/AGI/Downloads/apache-wicket-1.5.7/src/wicke
t-examples/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
[INFO] Webapp directory = C:\Users\AGI\Downloads\apache-wicket-1.5.7\src\wicket-
examples\src\main\webapp
[INFO] Starting jetty 7.4.2.v20110526 ...
2012-06-18 14:50:04.567:INFO::jetty-7.4.2.v20110526
2012-06-18 14:50:08.422:INFO::No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requ
ires one, please configure one.
2012-06-18 14:50:08.664:INFO:/:Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO  - ContextLoader              - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization
started
INFO  - XmlWebApplicationContext   - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: star
tup date [Mon Jun 18 14:50:08 GMT+07:00 2012]; root of context hierarchy
INFO  - XmlBeanDefinitionReader    - Loading XML bean definitions from class pat
h resource [applicationContext.xml]
INFO  - DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springf
ramework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@141622d: defining bean
s [contactDao,wicketApplication]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO  - ContextLoader              - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization
completed in 396 ms
2012-06-18 14:50:09.064:INFO::started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/,file:/C:/User
s/AGI/Downloads/apache-wicket-1.5.7/src/wicket-examples/src/main/webapp/},file:/
C:/Users/AGI/Downloads/apache-wicket-1.5.7/src/wicket-examples/src/main/webapp/
2012-06-18 14:50:13.260:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080 STARTI
NG
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
[INFO] Starting scanner at interval of 60 seconds.
```

I think, there is something wrong with the enunciate I am trying to, but I don't know where I should check because if I think I have done what the codehaus tell me to do. Would you guide me to the right track ?

For your attention I say thanks.

Comment: What is your actual problem? I can't see any error in the mave output. Looks like jetty is started and waiting to serve content

Comment: Nah, the problem is I didn't know what must I do in order to obtain the same result as the tutorial link described. The maven-wicket things is new to me. The api folder generated succesfully by enunciate, but the xml and json didn't. Yesterday, I tried to add annotation  @Produces("application/xml", "application/json") but still didn't work. I wondered why. Can you help me ? T.T
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try using enunciate 1.28.

I tried for my project with older version of the library without success and succeeded with the latest version.